# Proof that $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A^n$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, induction, solution-verification

Does my following inductive proof of the statement suffice?

---

Proof by induction:

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition that $A^n v = \lambda ^ n v$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 1}$, if $A v = \lambda v$.

1. Base step

$P(1)$ is true as $A^1 v = Av = \lambda v = \lambda ^1 v$.

2. Induction step

Let $P(n)$ be true for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 1}$, i.e., $A^k v = \lambda^k v$.

Then,

$$
\begin{align}
&A^{k + 1}v \\
= &A(A^kv) \\
= &A(\lambda^k v) \\
= &\lambda^k (Av) \\
= &\lambda^k (\lambda v) \\
= &\lambda^{k + 1}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, $P(k + 1)$ is true.

Hence, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 1} \, P(n)$ by mathematical induction.

---

I apologize for the messy formatting. Any help or confirmation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your proof is fine !

Comment: @Fred Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You can also show it with EVD of the matrix, where the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues has power $k$.